# OTC Pink Sheet Merger Acquistions

Tags: data-request

I was wondering if you may know of :

1. Databases that can be used to research up and coming future merger deals for companies that are listed in the OTC Market Pink sheets?
   I am having a hard time finding something simple  with this type of information to study.
   It would be very much appreciated for any information regarding Shell companies acquired, in order to follow in real time the effect it has on their market prices.
2. How to go about effectively measuring the good deals from the bad ones?
   In other words, what to look for to determine ahead of time if it most likely will be successful or not. To weigh against the ultimate conclusive result.

Comment: You're on opendata-SE so I cannot post my findings here because they're not open.  You should consider asking on quant-SE instead.